# Azure Maps API workaround for unsupported regions

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I am using Azure Maps API to for geocode reversal. Sometimes, it works and sometimes it doesn't. While researching I found a document- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/about-azure-maps. It says that the API is currently not supported for below countries-

- Argentina
- China
- India
- Morocco
- Pakistan
- South Korea

I am looking for a workaround. Is there any way I can use the API from India?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a VPN into a supported region. Note, if you do this, don't share the map publicly as it will show things that don't align with the views of these countries and can get your company into some trouble. Many of these countries will likely be unblocked in early 2019.

Comment: Thanks. I have figured a work around. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround which I figured out.

Create a function app in Azure and make an Http call to the Azure maps API. Make sure the app is hosted in a region where the Azure maps API is allowed (e.g. Central US).

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    string lattlong = req.Query["lattlong"];

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string location = httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/reverse/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key=<secret_key>&query=" + lattlong).Result;

    dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(location);

    return lattlong != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(data.addresses[0].address.municipality + ", " + data.addresses[0].address.country)
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Failed to get location.");
}
```

The function app should take the lattidue and longitude as parameters and make the Http call.

```
https://<function_app>.azurewebsites.net/api/GetLocation?code=1/<function_secret_key>&lattlong=13.097045900000001,77.59058569999999
```

The response from the Azure Maps API is returned successfully by the function app.

[image]